# RHEL 8 find-debuginfo.sh gdb-add-index: No index was created

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rhel8

Trying to generate rpm on RHEL8 Machine. The same rpm_build.sh script works fine on RHEL6 & RHEL7. But in RHEL 8 its failing to generate debuginfo packages.

RPM BUILD VERSION :
$ sudo yum install rpm-build
Package rpm-build-4.14.3-23.el8.x86_64 is already installed.

```
+ install -m 755 libclntshcore.so.12.1 /home/opc/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_lib-23.1.3-1.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/pam/libclntshcore.so.12.1
+ install -m 755 libnnz12.so /home/opc/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_lib-23.1.3-1.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/pam/libnnz12.so


/usr/lib/rpm/find-debuginfo.sh -j8 --strict-build-id -m -i --build-id-seed 23.1.3-1.el8 --unique-debug-suffix -23.1.3-1.el8.x86_64 --unique-debug-src-base my_lib-23.1.3-1.el8.x86_64 --run-dwz --dwz-low-mem-die-limit 10000000 --dwz-max-die-limit 110000000 -S debugsourcefiles.list /home/opc/rpmbuild/BUILD/my_lib-23.1.3

extracting debug info from /home/opc/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_lib23.1.3-1.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/pam/libclntshcore.so.12.1
extracting debug info from /home/opc/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_lib-23.1.3-1.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/pam/libnnz12.so

gdb-add-index: No index was created for /home/opc/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_lib-23.1.3-1.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/pam/libons.so
gdb-add-index: [Was there no debuginfo? Was there already an index?]
gdb-add-index: No index was created for /home/opc/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_lib-23.1.3-1.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/pam/libclntshcore.so.12.1
gdb-add-index: [Was there no debuginfo? Was there already an index?]
```

My Spec.file

```
Name:           my_lib-devel
Version:        %{pkg_version}
Release:        %{pkg_release}%{?dist}
Group:          System Environment/Libraries
Source0:        %{_sourcedir}/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz  


Requires:  my_lib

%global debug_package %{nil}

%global _lib_authn_api_filename libauthn_api.so
%global _package_name my_lib

%description
developemnt package 

%prep
%setup -q

%post -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun -p /sbin/ldconfig

%build 

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_includedir}/%{_package_name}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/doc/%{name}
cp *.h %{buildroot}/%{_includedir}/%{_package_name}
install -m 644 README %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/doc/%{name}/README
install -m 644 LICENCE %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/doc/%{name}/LICENCE

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/%{_includedir}/%{_package_name}/*.h

%doc %{_datadir}/doc/%{name}/*
```

Not sure why it complaints while extracting debug info
When I ran it on RHEL6 / RHEL7 same thing works fine . Is something is updated in RHEL8 which I'm missing or do I need to update the specs to work on RHEL8 . I have tried couple of solution Like %global debug_package %{nil} or %define debug_package %{nil} But nothing works.
Kindly Help !